# I am using a stereo 3D pen. What surface should I use?

Tags: build-surface

Using a 3D pen I printed a small box. However, I was doing it on plain paper and of course the paper didn't come off the plastic very well. It didn't matter for that specific case, but if I want to print something else, which non-sticky surface would you recommend? Is there any way to use transparent surface (so that I can put a paper with picture as a guide under it)?

Comment: I assume you want to draw with PLA?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a piece of glass, that's what most people using 3D printers have as a build surface.  An easy source of glass for pen use would be a picture frame but the edges are likely sharp so be careful.  Acrylic would also work and is easily obtained in small pieces from places like Lowes/Home Depot, I used Acrylic for some time on my Kossel.  The plastic can stick to Acrylic very well but I had no issues using it with my printer, just test it out and see what process works if you go that route.

Comment: Note that you can improve the adhesion to glass by applying a layers of gluestick, hairspray or similar as well (there are many options and opinions about this).

Comment: I'm curious what brand of pen you are using. I haven't found a STL one yet, and might be interested.

Answer (score 0):

Someone trying to get a surface to not stick. This is a first. I would try glass first. If you still have issues, I would look into coated surface, like an old tefflon pan (do not cook with PLA residue). I would suggest oil but you might start a fire..

Answer (score 0):

You might want to experiment using Kapton tape. Although it's yellow-coloured, it is transparent and provides a good surface for hit-bed adhesion. You should be able to remove it from your print by flexing it.

Attaching it to your paper sheet is a one-way process, but you can use guide marks on the paper below.

Answer (score 0):

I use parchment paper, the kind that you buy on sheets for baking.

It come off nicely but there are adhesion problems if you want to do sharp corners.

I prefer using ordinary printer paper for that. You can simply soak any scraps of paper off in a sink.